# A basic doubt on Lipschitz continuity

Tags: real-analysis, lipschitz-functions

What is the necessary and sufficient condition on matrix $A$ such that $h(x) = Ax$ is lipschitz continuous ? $A $ is a $m \times n$ matrix and $x$ is $n \times 1$ matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Always will be Lipschitz:
$$\|A(x-y)\|\le|||A|||\,\|x-y\|,$$
with $|||\cdot|||$ the [operator norm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_norm) associated to $\|\cdot\|$.

Comment: But, for that the linear map needs to be continuous, right.

Comment: @user148951, in finite dimension, linear maps are continuous.